# PHP str_starts_with and str_ends_with functions not working as expected

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, cron-task

I have a php file that works well when I run it on browser but when I schedule it to run via cpanel cronjob, strangely it doesn't work. I spoke at length with the hosting company(namecheap) but they insisted the cron environment was ok, and the problem might be from my code. So I decided to debug my code thoroughly to find out which functions were preventing the file from running via cronjob. This is the code I used for the debugging:

```
$funcs = ['str_starts_with', 'str_ends_with', 'writegames', 'is_array'];
foreach($funcs as $fun) {
    if(function_exists($fun)){
        echo $fun." exists\n";
    } else {
        echo $fun." doesn't exist\n";
    }
}
//NB: writegames is a custom function I wrote, so it exists
```

Here is what I found out: ALL the functions echo 'EXISTS' when I run this code on browser, but when I schedule it via cpanel cronjob, 'str_starts_with' and 'str_end_with' echo 'DOESNT EXIST', how is this even possible? I have PHP 8.0 enabled on my cpanel, I was wondering if there's some other thing which I was supposed to set which I didn't set or should I move to PHP 8.1? At this point, I'm very confused. Thanks.

Comment: add in `echo 'PHP version: ' . phpversion();` to your code to confirm.. guess `str_starts_with` are just sugar wrapping `mb_substr($a, 0, mb_strlen($b))` etc

Comment: It is quite possible that Cpanel has only configured the webserver to use PHP 8.x while cronjobs use the server's default 7.x version. If your cronjob is configured to simply run `php /path/to/your/script` you might need to change it to `/path/to/php-8.0/bin/php /path/to/your/script`. You'd just need to find out where the PHP 8.0 binary is stored on your server.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Your comment was so so helpful. The phpversion() function helped me find out the webserver was running PHP 8.0.26 while the cron was running PHP 7.4.33, which is exactly why str_starts_with wasn't working. Also, I always thought about using strpos as a work around for str_starts_with, but I just learnt a new function from you right now, mb_substr, and it seems pretty more straightforward to use than strpos. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thanks a lot for your comment, My cronjob is configured to `/usr/local/bin/php /home/path/to/script`, I guess what needs to change is `/usr/local/bin/php`. Is there a way I can find the php 8 binary folder myself? Or should I write to my hosting provider? Because I'm not sure I have access to `/usr/local/bin/php`, I think I can only access `/home/path/to/script`.

Comment: @Chimdi you can write a quick PHP page that does `echo PHP_BINARY;` and access that from your browser. That should point to the PHP 8 binary. It might point to `php-fpm` but that should be in the same folder as the regular binary.

Comment: @rickdenhaan `echo PHP_BINARY;` gave me `/usr/local/bin/lsphp`, so I used it to replace `/usr/local/bin/php`, the code still didn't work and `echo phpversion()` still printed PHP 7 but what happened was that an actual system error message "Call to undefined function str_starts_with()" was sent to my cron output file. 

However, your answers already educated me so I knew the right questions to ask, I wrote to support again, told them my webserver is running PHP 8 while my cron is running PHP 7, within few seconds, the staff configured my cpanel to PHP 8 and everythin is fine now. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

you can write the functions yourself.

```
    <?php
 //str_starts_with
 if(!function_exists('str_starts_with')) {
     echo 'str_starts_with doesn\'t exist<br/>';
     function str_starts_with($haystack,$needle) {
         //str_starts_with(string $haystack, string $needle): bool

         $strlen_needle = mb_strlen($needle);
         if(mb_substr($haystack,0,$strlen_needle)==$needle) {
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
 }
 
 //str_ends_with
  if(!function_exists('str_ends_with')) {
     echo 'str_ends_with doesn\'t exist<br/>';
     //str_ends_with(string $haystack, string $needle): bool
     function str_ends_with($haystack,$needle) {
         //str_starts_with(string $haystack, string $needle): bool

         $strlen_needle = mb_strlen($needle);
         if(mb_substr($haystack,-$strlen_needle,$strlen_needle)==$needle) {
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
 }
 
 // Tests:
 if(str_starts_with('hello world','hello')) {echo 'start with hello';}
 echo '<br/>';
if(str_ends_with('hello world','world')) {echo 'end with world';};
```

[how to and test video](https://youtu.be/z9ix310FnIA)

Answer (score 1):

Just like @LawrenceCherone and @rickdenhaan pointed out in the comments. My webserver was running on PHP 8 while my cron was running on PHP 7 because the cpanel was configured to PHP 7.

I wrote to the Hosting agency to configure my cpanel to PHP 8 which they did within seconds and everything started working fine again.

Alternatively, assuming I didn't choose to configure my cpanel to PHP 8, this is the code I would have used, for PHP 7 up to PHP 4:

```
function str_starts_with($val, $str) {
    if(mb_substr($val, 0, mb_strlen($str)) == $str) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function str_ends_with($val, $str) {
    if(mb_substr($val, -mb_strlen($str), mb_strlen($str)) == $str) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To test it:

```
$string = 'stackoverflow';
$start = 'stack';
$end = 'flow';

if(str_starts_with($string, $start)) {
    echo 'yes'; //echoes yes
} else {
    echo 'no';
}

if(str_ends_with($string, $end)) {
    echo 'yes'; //echoes yes
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```